# Codeigniter - Make sure that the session is always up-to-date with the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

When the user logs in, I get their session info from the database and save it in the `ci_sessions` table in the database.

I have one problem. When a user logs in, I greet them from the info that is saved in the session. For e.g., `Welcome, <?php echo $first_name; ?>`

However, there is this number on my `users` database table where I store a number. That number is something that is also saved in the `ci_sessions` table. I have called that number `entry`. So, when the user logs in, on the left hand side of the header, it says `Your Entry Points: <?php echo $entry; ?>`.

I tried to change the `entry` from my `users` database table, but it won't effect the entry point that is shown to the user in the header because I'm doing an echo from the session.

How do I make sure that my session is always updated in every page. In other words, how do I update my session everytime the user refreshes his page so if I change the `entry` value manually from database, he is shown that new entry after he refreshes the page?

My code:

```
<?php

$entry = $this->session->userdata('entry');
$email = $this->session->userdata('email');
$sql = "SELECT entry from users WHERE email = '" . $email . "' LIMIT 1";
$sess_data = array(
            'entry' => $entry,
            'email' => $email,
            );
$this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
?>
```

This unfortunately doesn't work for some reason. Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Because you don't send the query to the database, you have an empty sess_data array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer. I actually have exactly the same problem. I'm hosting an ecommerce proyect in Godaddy and tried to solve session problems by saving them to database since it seems you can not update cookies on the fly with this hosting provider. I mean, your problem in the database is exactly mine, but in the CI session (cookie).

I guess the best option is to save this variable to a separate field in the database, update it manually and match it with the Session ID.

It's a shame, because in my development server it works just fine.

Comment: What I ended up doing was doing a query in my header.php file which is included in every single page and in the query, I receive the user's information from the database and show it to the user. 
Eg. `Hey, $first_name`. The variable `first_name` refers to the row that I got from the query.